# HTTP call to send data to server using Axios/Axios-retry

Tags: node.js, axios

I have a JSON object that I wish to send to a server using the server's API key. I wish to have a retry count of 3 so that I can retry sending data if previous calls fail.

I am not sure whether to use 'axios-retry' or 'retry-axios'.
How do I configure the Content-Type in the header, and where do I add the API key and the data to be sent. My present code looks like this:

```
const axiosRetry = require('axios-retry');
axiosRetry(axios, { retries: 3 });

var data = { /*----My JSON Object----*/ };

axios.post('my url', data, {
    headers: {
        'Authorization': 'API_Key',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
})
.then(function(response){
    console.log(response);
})
.catch(function(error){
    console.log(error);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use axios instead, it is a Promise based HTTP client for the browser and node.js

```
var axios = require('axios')
axios.post(url,data, {
headers: {
    'authorization': your_token,
    'Accept' : 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}

}).then(response => {
// return  response;
}).catch((error) => {
//return  error;
});
```

Comment: This works, but it fails to retry. Is there an option to retry if there was any error similar to axios-retry?

Comment: You tried to add same configuration to your axios request? add API_KEY and Content-Type in header and try.